# How to configure sitecore rich text editor not to replace url to relative.

Tags: richtext-editor, links

I have strange behavior at Rich Text editor (I heard that everyone had it), 
when user add some Absolute url for example, *https://www.example.com/mypage/someextra*, after save Sitecore replace it to relative one, */mypage/someextra.*
How to solve such issue?

Comment: I believe this s the expected functionality if you are using internal links as they should resolve to the domain of your Site. Can you explain a little further why your don't want Sitecore to use relative urls? we can then help you a bit more with the options here.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I need to have full links for have it at emails

Answer (score 1):

Use hyperlink instead of sitecore link
[image]

[image]